# AndroidJavaObject initialization fails NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

The error: `AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/util/UUID;.(J)V"`

The code: `var psshUuid = new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.UUID", 0x1077EFECC0B24D02L, 0xACE33C1E52E2FB4BL);`

java.util.UUID takes two longs in its constructor - I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. This is in Unity, coding in C#. Also, does anyone know what the (J)V part of the error means?

Comment: Did you write the native android part ? if so then you might forget to set the "Context" to unity android player in your native constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Java didn't like that these numbers are technically ulongs.